# Text/Code highlight with jsDoc

Tags: jsdoc

jsDoc seems to support most of the MD syntax, but when it comes to highlighting a single reserved word or text, I cannot find a usable tag for that.

In the MD syntax I can use `word`, which would set a grey background and a different font, so you can see it clearly, same as on StackOverflow - `word`.

In jsDoc, whether I use `word` or <code>word</code>, the effect is just setting italic style to the word, which cannot be clearly seen as a reserved word.

Is there any syntax in jsDoc to clearly highlight a word or a text string, like `some text` in MD, to look like `some text`?

Alternatively, is there a way to customize it - provide my own CSS for a standard MD tag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JSDoc documentation seems to be using `<code>` tag, and it highlights the text using a grey background like you want by setting it on the `code` tag properties defined on the `usejavadoc.css` file:

From http://usejsdoc.org/tags-name.html:

[image]

There is a guide on how to edit or create your own JSDoc template, with a section on how to override the default template layout file:

http://usejsdoc.org/about-configuring-default-template.html#overriding-the-default-template-s-layout-file

But for something as simple as this, you don't even have to go that far. Just edit the css fragment, before or after generation, and set the `background-color` you want for the `code` tag. You may do it before generation by editing this line and setting the background color you want:

https://github.com/jsdoc3/jsdoc/blob/5a58bdf5a551844f12b46be6436aefd3c41e0393/templates/default/static/styles/jsdoc-default.css#L257

Or, if that doesn't work, overriding the property by adding

```
code {
  background-color: #DEDEDE !important;
}
```

to the file.

As an alternative you can use a framework like [qooxdoo](http://qooxdoo.org/) to generate your documentation using JSDoc-like comments. According to their API reference you may use `<pre class="javascript">` for inline javascript syntax code highlighting, and it looks pretty nice: http://manual.qooxdoo.org/3.0/pages/development/api_jsdoc_ref.html#html